# Get next struct item from array in HIve

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table with field of Array of Structures type:

```
CREATE TABLE complex_types(
   key int, 
   value ARRAY<STRUCT<status:string,method:string>>
);

INSERT INTO TABLE complex_types
SELECT row_number() over () as key,
  ARRAY(
     named_struct('status', 'OK', 'method', 'Method 1'),
     named_struct('status', 'Error', 'method', 'Method 2'),
     named_struct('status', 'Failed', 'method', 'Method 3')
  ) as value
FROM some_table LIMIT 10
```

When I access the whole structure by index, it returns a correct item.

```
select key, value[0], value[1] from complex_types
```

Result is

```
key _c1 _c2
1   {"status":"OK","method":"Method 1"} {"status":"Error","method":"Method 2"}
2   {"status":"OK","method":"Method 1"} {"status":"Error","method":"Method 2"}
3   {"status":"OK","method":"Method 1"} {"status":"Error","method":"Method 2"}
```

But if I specify the key for structure item, it returns value from last item:

```
select key, value[0].method, value[1].method from complex_types
```

and result is

```
key _c1 _c2
1   Method 2    Method 2
2   Method 2    Method 2
3   Method 2    Method 2
```

Thank you

Comment: it works fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
It looks like the issue is present in HDP Ambari Hive View 2.0 only.
The query works fine in hive console and in Ambari Hive View 1st version.